# How do I successfully describe a story?

Tags: creative-writing

I try to, but always end up shutting down and thinking it's stupid. Especially when I haven't been writing it for long. Help!

Comment: Describe it to whom and for what purpose?  To a publisher in a pitch letter?  To shoppers on Amazon?  To your friends and family so they'll understand how you spend your days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is kind of a broad question, but i suggest trying to pinpoint exactly what you find stupid about it, and seeing how you can make it less stupid. 
Maybe think of plans for future characters or future conflicts, think about what's cool about your villain, etc.
Unfortunately, there is no set answer for "How do i story". You just have to write and see what comes out.

Comment: Furthermore - do you plan your stories out in advance or just sit down and write?

Comment: @Thomo I sit down and write.

Comment: @DJFluffy - planning your story out may help with this. I find it works for me as it breaks  it up into achievable goals. Something to try at least.